# Am I using randomRIO wrong?

Tags: haskell, random, io, functional-programming

I'm trying to show on Terminal a random number between 1 and 7...

```
nRandom :: IO ()
nRandom = do
    number <- randomRIO (1,7)
    putStrLn ("Your random number is: "++show number)
```

...but ghc doesn't compile it and I get errors like:

```
No instance for (Random a0) arising from a use of `randomRIO'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Random Bool -- Defined in `System.Random'
  instance Random Foreign.C.Types.CChar -- Defined in `System.Random'
  instance Random Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `System.Random'
  ...plus 33 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block: number <- randomRIO (1, 7)
In the expression:
  do { number <- randomRIO (1, 7);
       putStrLn ("Your random number is: " ++ show number) }
In an equation for `nRandom':
    nRandom
      = do { number <- randomRIO (1, 7);
             putStrLn ("Your random number is: " ++ show number) }
```

and,

```
No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `1'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus 37 others
In the expression: 1
In the first argument of `randomRIO', namely `(1, 7)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: number <- randomRIO (1, 7)
```

Can anyone say me what am I doing wrong? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that both `randomRIO` and `show` are polymorphic, so the compiler doesn't know which type to pick for `number`.  You can add a type annotation, e.g.

```
nRandom :: IO ()
nRandom = do
    number <- randomRIO (1,7) :: IO Int
    putStrLn ("Your random number is: "++show number)
```

to help the compiler figure it out.   I've attached the annotation to the expression `randomRIO (1,7)`, which is why it's `IO Int` instead of just `Int` (which is `number`s type).